# Live form validation as you type

Tags: jquery, validation, forms, live

I'm looking for jQuery plugin, that validates form as user types.

I know, there is powerful [jQuery.Validation](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) plugin, but it does't provides live validation feature. First validation happens only after submit, so, when user fills some fields incorrect, it will not know about this, until it presses submit button.

The plugin, I'm looking for, should be something, like [LiveValidation](http://livevalidation.com/) plugin, available for Prototype.

Answer (score 2):

Try this: http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/jquery-form-validator-because-form-validation-is-a-mess/

If that is not what you are looking for then go to "55 jQuery Form Plugins To Download And Use" - http://www.designyourway.net/blog/resources/55-jquery-form-plugins-to-download-and-use/

Maybe you will find something there that suits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

The prototype.js version of LiveValidation is optimized for Ruby on Rails. If you are using jQuery then why not just use the [standalone LiveValidation version](http://livevalidation.com/javascripts/src/1.3/livevalidation_standalone.js).

Per the original author it is for:

> using with any other javascript framework, or when having one at all would be overkill